# Proving$ (\mathbb{R}^\omega, \tau_{box})$ is not metrisable using the sequence lemma

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove $(\mathbb{R}^\omega, \tau_{box})$ is not metrisable.

The sequence lemma to show a topology is not metrisable:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$. Then $a \in \bar{A}$ whenever there exists a sequence $(x_j)$ in A converges to a.

This is the proof:

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ be the set of all sequences $x \in X$ such that $x(n) \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

We now show $a$ is in the closure of A.

Let $u \subset X$ be the basis element $u=\prod_{j \in \mathbb{N}} u_j$  where for each j, $u_j \in \mathbb{R}$ is open and $o \in u_j$

Then $(-a_j, a_j) < u_j$.

Taking $x \in X$ with $x(j)=\frac{a_j}{2}$ it follows $x \in u \cap A$

Assume $(\delta_j)$ us a sequence in A converging to 0 in X.

Then take $u=\prod_{j \in \mathbb{N}} u_j$ with $(-a_j, a_j) < u_j$ where $a_j = (\delta_j (j) >0$

Then $0 \in u$ and $\delta_j \notin u$ for any j.

I do not understand this proof, what is the general plan of this proof?

What does it mean to say something is a basis element?

Why is showing $x \in u \cap A$ significant?

Why is showing  $(-a_j, a_j) < u_j$ significant?

How is $u=\prod_{j \in \mathbb{N}} u_j$ interpreted?

Comment: 1.We should re-define $A$ as $\{x :\forall n \;(x(n)>0)\}$ because,as you have it, $\bar 0=(0,0,0,...)\in A$....  2..."We show $a\in \bar A$" should say $0$,not $a$.... 3.Write $(-a_j,a_j)\subset U_j$, not "$<u_j$".... 4. The plan is to show that $\bar 0$ has a nbhd $u$ containing no member of $\{\delta_j :j\in N\}$ contradicting the convergence of the sequence $(\delta_j)_{j\in N}$ to $\bar 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The correct term is base, not basis. A base element would, I assume, mean a member of a base. An interpretation of $\prod_{j\in N}u_j$ is the set of all real sequences $(r_j)_{j\in N}$ such that $r_j\in u_j$ for each $j.$ The usual base for the box product on $R^N$ is the set of all $\prod_{j\in N}u_j$, where each $u_j$ is an open real interval. The idea of the the proof is : (1). Suppose that $d$ is a metric  and $\bar 0=(0,0,0,...)\in R^N.$ (2). Then for each $k\in N$ the open ball $B_d(\bar 0,1/k)$ has a subset $\prod_{n\in N}(-r_{n,k},\;r_{n,k})$ where each $r_{n,k}>0.$ So the sequence $s_k=(r_{1,k}/2,\;r_{2,k}/2,\;r_{3,k}/2,...)$ belongs to $B_d(\bar 0,1/k)$...(3)Now let $s_j=r_{j,j}/4$ for each $j,$ and let $U=\prod_{j\in N}(-s_j,s_j).$ Then $U$ is a neighborhood of $\bar 0,$ and contains no member of $\{s_k: k\in N\}.$ (4) But for some $t>0$ we must have $U\supset B_d(\bar 0,t)$ and for any sufficiently large $k\in N$ we have $1/k<t,$ which implies $s_k\in B_d(\bar 0,1/k)\subset B_d(\bar 0,t)\subset U,$ contradicting $s_k\not \in U.$